# X isn't working with nvidia geforce, no screens found

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I recently installed ubuntu on a Lenovo Y500 with a Nvidia geforce chip. startx does not work.

First I was told that module nvidia did not exist, so I installed nvidia-current, which eliminated that issue. My X log file says my driver ought to be supporting my gpu. However, the file also returns the following warnings:

```
Falling back to old probe method for vesa
Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
```

And eventually:

```
Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.

Failing initialization o x screen 0
```

So for some reason my GPU isn't initializing, even though my driver should be working with it.

Running startx reveals:

```
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Input/Output error).
```

But that doesn't get recorded in the log file, for some reason. In dev, I can find the nvidia0 file, but when I nano it it's empty. I suspect this is because of the file type, not its contents and I'm just being stupid, but I thought it might be relevant. Nothing else I can think of reveals anything about this file.

So I thought, maybe it's a permissions issue. Sudo startx returned the same results. Logging in as root changes nothing.

I am now stuck. I can come up with nothing else. Help me, askubuntu, you're my only hope!

Comment: What GPU do you use?

Comment: Same problem here with a Lenovo Y500, running GT 750M.

Comment: It seems that's a general problem for several users: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/567297/linux-3-10-driver-crash/